# Не работает телеграмм бот

Tags: java, telegram-bot, бот

```
Ошибка целиком:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/RemovalListener
    at com.google.inject.internal.InheritingState.<init>(InheritingState.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.getState(InjectorShell.java:208)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.lock(InjectorShell.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:102)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.ApiContext.getInjector(ApiContext.java:48)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.ApiContext.getInstance(ApiContext.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.<init>(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:16)
    at Bot.<init>(Bot.java:8)
    at Bot.main(Bot.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.RemovalListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 12 more
```

класс бот

```
  import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException;

public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger");

        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi =new TelegramBotsApi();
        try{
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new Bot());
        }catch (TelegramApiRequestException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

    }

    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "FrilanceExampleBot";
    }

    public String getBotToken() {
        return "1009780375:AAE5zUAX8BtUOd7cFrvJSWyLXzBzkbcP3ts";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>WeatherBot</groupId>
    <artifactId>Bot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

День убил, но нашел нужное.
https://www.surgebook.com/open/book/pishem-telegram-bota-na-java/predoslovie_g5
следуйте и все получится.
Кроме того, обязательно включайте VPN

Исходники:
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


</project>
```

Main:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new Bot());
        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Bot:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMediaGroup;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        update.getUpdateId();

        String chat_id = String.valueOf(update.getMessage().getChatId());
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage().setChatId(chat_id);

        if(update.getMessage().getText().equals("Привет")){
            sendMessage.setText("Привет дружище");
            try {
                execute(sendMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```